# Possible to access an AWS public dataset using Cyberduck?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cyberduck

Cyberduck version: Version 7.9.2

Cyberduck is designed to access non-public AWS buckets. It asks for:

- Server
- Port
- Access Key ID
- Secret Access Key

The Registry of Open Data on AWS provides this information for an open dataset (using the example at https://registry.opendata.aws/target/):

- **Resource type:** S3 Bucket
- **Amazon Resource Name (ARN):** arn:aws:s3:::gdc-target-phs000218-2-open
- **AWS Region:** us-east-1
- **AWS CLI Access (No AWS account required):** aws s3 ls s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open/ --no-sign-request

Is there a version of `s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open` that can be used in Cyberduck to connect to the data?

Comment: The `--no-sign-request` parameter tells the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to _not_ provide credentials, which will work with public buckets (except those marked as 'Requester Pays'). However, it is unlikely that CyberDuck has such an option. Sounds like a good opportunity to learn how to use the AWS CLI!

Answer (score 2):

If the bucket is public, *any* AWS credentials will suffice. So as long as you can [create an AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-and-activate-aws-account/), you only need to [create an IAM user for yourself with programmatic access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html#id_users_create_cliwpsapi), and you are all set.

No doubt, it's a pain because creating an AWS account needs your credit (or debit) card! But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825406/1094109 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44825406/1094109

I tried this with `s3://gdc-target-phs000218-2-open` and it worked:

[image: roda-gdc-target-phs000218-2-open]

For RODA buckets that provide public access to specific prefixes, you'd need to edit the path to suit. E.g. `s3://cellpainting-gallery/cpg0000-jump-pilot/source_4/` (this is a RODA bucket maintained by us, yet to be released fully)

NOTE: The screenshots below show a different URL that's no longer operational. The correct URL is `s3://cellpainting-gallery/cpg0000-jump-pilot/source_4/`

[image: roda-cellpainting-gallery]

Answer (score 0):

No, it's explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3) that

> You must obtain the login credentials [in order to connect to Amazon S3 in Cyberduck]